# Livedata and Room queries

Tags: java, android, mvvm

I am using Room database and live data. I have no problem with ui related data because I am observing to database query from activity via view model.  But I need some data in viewmodel(not in activity) from db, I can't use it there because livedata is not working without observation. If I try to get this data without Livedata from db, I am getting you can't get data from db in ui thread error. How can I resolve it?

Ps: I am accessing db via repository.

My DAO:

```
@Query("SELECT * from loggedUser limit 1")
LiveData<LoggedUser> getLoggedUser();
```

Repository:

```
public LiveData<LoggedUser> executeGetLoggedUser() {
    return userDao.getLoggedUser();
}
```

Viewmodel:

```
    private MediatorLiveData<LoggedUser> loggedUser = new MediatorLiveData<>();
    final LiveData<LoggedUser> tt = ribonyRepository.executeGetLoggedUser();
    loggedUser.addSource(tt, new Observer<LoggedUser>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(@Nullable LoggedUser loggedUser) {
             //No data is coming to here
        }
    });
```

Comment: Try to observe tt and not loggedUser

Comment: Observing requires "activity" as an argument. I need it in view model